# Is it possible to install spyder-kernels in a new anaconda virtual environment at its creation moment?

Tags: anaconda, spyder, compatibility, virtual-environment

I've been struggling with Anaconda virtual environments and Spyder. I want to know if there's is a way to configure Anaconda so that whenever I create a new virtual environment, the spyder-kernel module is automatically installed in it. That would make easier to switch between virtual environments while using Spyder.
I love Spyder but I'm thinking of moving to VSCode or PyCharm because of this.

I googled my question and found no useful answers.

Comment: conda env create -f a_common_environment_with_spyder.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and documented [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#adding-default-packages-to-new-environments-automatically).

In a `conda` prompt enter:

```
conda config --add create_default_packages package_name_1 package_name_2
```

When later creating new environments, for example:

```
conda create -n new_env
```

the packages `package_name_1` and `package_name_2` will be automatically installed.

Note that this will also install all the dependencies of these packages, including python. If you want to have a specific version of one of these dependencies, just specify that when you create the environment.

Below is an example how to do automatically install `spyder-kernels` when creating new environments, and with the optional setting to specifying a python version and using `conda-forge` channel when creating a new environment.

First add `spyder-kernels` to the default package config (this is a one time config command, all environments created after this will install `spyder-kernels`) :

```
conda config --add create_default_packages spyder-kernels
```

Later, I create my environment (here I don't have to ask to install `spyder-kernels`):

```
conda create -n new_env -c conda-forge python=3.9 -y
```

With the (partial) output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: path_to_environments\envs\new_env

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.9
    - spyder-kernels

...
```